# Why is Visual Studio telling me that my module is cannot be found with TypeScript and Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, angular

I'm using Visual Studio with the Angular 2 Webpack Starter and sometime when I import a component, it just toys with me and tells me that the path is bad, then I just modify one letter (generally the 's' at the end of the filename) and it's good. It's like it's watching an old version of the project.
 Very weird... Am I the only one ?:D

Comment: Are you using resharper?

Comment: Don't think so since it's not in installed package and I can install it.